# What's the "Alpha" option in the New Image Texture Node?

Tags: node-editor, image, transparency

I'm wondering whether or not new Blender image nodes are baked with an alpha channel built into them by default. From this photo, it seems that's the case, but I'm not completely sure this is what I think it is. It might sound obvious but I'm still new to Blender and I'm not sure. I'm wondering because I need my baked image to have an alpha channel in it in order to import it into Unity. This picture is what I'm wondering about. Thanks in advance.

[image]